# How to declare a selected option in select statement with a dynamic input from database?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on an input mask for a little software tool. Therefore I have different possibilities to allow the user to give his input (input types). Also I have a select field for choosing an answer out of a given sort order. These answers are read from a table of my database. It is dynamic.

After the user selected all the necessary input, he can update the values in the table by clicking on a submit button (with a formula). After this clicking process, the values in the database get updated via SQL, read again and given out. So with no problem the user can see instantly his changes.

My aim is to show the updated values in the input fields, so the user can see them. And this is also no problem. But not at the select box. It would be perfect, if the last selected option in the select box would be declared as the selected option. And now my question is:

Is it possible to declare a option as selected on a dynamic list in a select box?

```
<div class="select">
   <select name="strategy">
       <?php
           $resultSet=$conn->query("SELECT test_strategy FROM strategies");
              while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                 $strategy = $rows['test_strategy'];
                 echo "<option id='option' value='$strategy'>$strategy</option>";
            }
        ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially Fetch the Updated value from the Data base and assign in a variable
Example : iam using $FetchtheUpdatevalueformDB

```
<div class="select">
   <select name="strategy">
       <?php
           $resultSet=$conn->query("SELECT test_strategy FROM strategies");
              while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                  $Selected="";
                  if($FetchtheUpdatevariableformDB==$strategy){
                  $Selected="selected";
                  }
                 $strategy = $rows['test_strategy'];
                 echo "<option id='option' value='$strategy' ".$Selected.">$strategy</option>";
            }
        ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to get the users value to see if it matches and then you can apply the `selected` option to your element.

So you will need a variable with the current users selected `test_strategy` which i guess is saved in your users table. It's just a simple select query like you did above.

After you have it you can put an `if` condition in your loop like:

```
<?php
$resultSet=$conn->query("SELECT test_strategy FROM strategies");
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
    $strategy = $rows['test_strategy'];
    if($usersStrategy == $strategy){
        echo "<option id='option' value='$strategy' selected>$strategy</option>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<option id='option' value='$strategy'>$strategy</option>";
    }
}
?>
```